# Prawn CannotFit error for table cell with colspan and width

Tags: ruby, prawn

When trying to create table like http://rghost.ru/46587227.view with Prawn, it causes a CannotFit error:

```
first = {:content=>"Foooo fo foooooo",:width=>50,:align=>:center}
second = {:content=>"Foooo",:colspan=>2,:width=>70,:align=>:center}
third = {:content=>"fooooooooooo, fooooooooooooo, fooo, foooooo fooooo",:width=>55,:align=>:center}
fourth = {:content=>"Bar",:width=>20,:align=>:center}

table_content = [[
  first,
  [[second],[third,fourth]]
]]
pdf.move_down(20)
pdf.table(table_content)
```

Comment: and when second width is 100 and third and forth 50 work fine, but this not for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prawn has problems calculating cell sizes for cells with `colspan`.

I was able to work around this issue by following these rules:

- don't assign `width` to a cell with `colspan`
- give the table the correct total width

#### Applied to your example

```
 first = { content: "Foooo fo foooooo", rowspan: 2, width: 50 }
second = { content: "Foooo", colspan: 2 } # <- avoid width here!
 third = { content: "fooooooooooo, fooooooooooooo, fooo, foooooo fooooo", width: 55 }
fourth = { content: "Bar", width: 20 }

Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") do |pdf|
  table_content = [ [first, second       ],
                    [       third, fourth],
                    [1,     2,     3     ] ]
  pdf.move_down(20)
  pdf.table(table_content, width: 50+55+20, cell_style: {align: :center})
end
```

#### Output

[image: PDF]

Comment: Good solution, but I`m invented dirty hack to avoid this problem.
No use colspan but usual table with borders with one side, provide like colspan behaviour. Thanks again for your reply!